# Output of the Following Short argc & argv Code

Tags: c++, argv, argc

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;

    i = 1;
    while (i < argc) {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }

}
```

**Command line arguments are listed as b f i**

I'm just learning about argc and argv, but from what I understand, argc is the number of arguments passed from the command line (3 in this case), and argv is the array of these arguments, [b f i] in this case. So using that, I intuitively think that this loop should output argv[1], then argv[2], then terminate. The final output would therefore be:

**f**

**i**

However, the solution given is:

**b**

**f**

**i**

Which is baffling to me. Would anyone be able to explain where I'm going wrong with my thought process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv[0]` is actually the name you used to run the program.

So if you ran:

```
./myProgram b f i
```

`argv` contains `["./myProgram", "b", "f", "i"]`, and `argc == 4`.

(This isn't actually part of The Standard, but is the normal behaviour on most platforms).

As a mildly interesting aside, note it is guaranteed that `argv[argc]==nullptr`, so you could iterate over the valid pointers, rather than using an index, if you wanted to.

A `for` loop keeps the iteration logic more self-contained than a `while`; the more common form of the loop you have written would be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << '\n'; // see note below
}
```

---

Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).

Comment: Ohhh, I see, so this is argv is actually an array with 4 elements. That clears this question right up and also makes the remainder of my argc/argv practice intuitive, thank you very much!

Comment: @Mock Please also see the extra note I just added on some other style issues.

Comment: Is `endl` bad practice because it doesn't use the namespace, or is there some other reason ?

Comment: @user1952500 Read the link: it is confusing because it does 2 unrelated things, and people often misunderstand that.